# Daily Attendance Summed Weekly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Greetings all,

    I’m wondering if I could get some insights on the best way to get Attendance data.
I need get every viable in(AttendanceTypeID = 1) and out(AttendanceTypeID = 2) pairs in a day. Sum up the time values up per employee by week starting Sunday and ending Saturday.  The closet in to the an out is the business rule for what is needed, and there may be many in/out pairs in a single day.  I am also anchored to SQL 2008 logic since some of our customers are still using SQL 2008.  I have seen a view examples using CTE’s, which I prefer, but they had used lead,lag, LastVal, NestVal functions which start in 2012.
Output.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1946217.aspx?Time+Attendance+working+hours
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/solving-complex-t-sql-problems,-step-by-step/

```
CREATE TABLE tblAttendance
(
[AttendanceID] int, 
[DepartmentID] int, 
[EmployeeID] int, 
[AttendanceDate] datetime, 
[AttendanceTime] varchar(8), 
[AttendanceTypeID] int, 
[AttendanceCodeID] int, 
[Submitted] int
);



INSERT INTO tblAttendance
    ([AttendanceID], [DepartmentID], [EmployeeID], [AttendanceDate], 
[AttendanceTime], [AttendanceTypeID], [AttendanceCodeID], [Submitted])
    VALUES
        (838, 33, 260, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (839, 33, 260, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '22:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (836, 41, 344, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (837, 41, 344, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '22:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (812, 33, 348, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (813, 33, 348, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '12:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (814, 33, 350, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (815, 33, 350, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '12:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (930, 7, 361, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (931, 7, 361, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (940, 19, 361, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '8:55:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (941, 19, 361, '2018-02-26 00:00:00', '10:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (824, 1, 114, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '23:59:57', 2, 1, 0),
        (816, 33, 206, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '11:12:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (819, 33, 206, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '11:16:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (822, 1, 350, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '0:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (829, 33, 350, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '16:15:30', 1, 1, 0),
        (830, 33, 359, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '16:15:30', 1, 1, 0),
        (932, 7, 361, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (933, 7, 361, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (942, 19, 361, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '8:30:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (943, 19, 361, '2018-02-27 00:00:00', '10:30:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (835, 33, 206, '2018-02-28 00:00:00', '9:23:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (934, 7, 361, '2018-02-28 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (935, 7, 361, '2018-02-28 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (944, 19, 361, '2018-02-28 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (945, 19, 361, '2018-02-28 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (936, 7, 361, '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (937, 7, 361, '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (946, 19, 361, '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (947, 19, 361, '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '9:30:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (840, 33, 350, '2018-03-02 00:00:00', '8:21:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (841, 33, 350, '2018-03-02 00:00:00', '8:22:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (938, 7, 361, '2018-03-02 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (939, 7, 361, '2018-03-02 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (948, 19, 361, '2018-03-02 00:00:00', '9:01:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (949, 19, 361, '2018-03-02 00:00:00', '10:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (894, 33, 260, '2018-03-05 00:00:00', '6:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (895, 33, 260, '2018-03-05 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (859, 33, 348, '2018-03-05 00:00:00', '9:30:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (860, 33, 348, '2018-03-05 00:00:00', '9:30:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (842, 33, 206, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '13:21:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (856, 33, 206, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '2:51:27', 2, 1, 0),
        (848, 33, 206, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '13:57:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (843, 33, 260, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '14:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (861, 33, 348, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '9:30:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (862, 33, 348, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '9:31:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (853, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '2:32:36', 1, 1, 0),
        (854, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '2:48:54', 1, 1, 0),
        (855, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '2:49:11', 1, 1, 0),
        (857, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '2:52:19', 1, 1, 0),
        (844, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '13:32:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (846, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '13:53:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (845, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '13:35:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (850, 33, 350, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '14:06:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (847, 33, 359, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '13:56:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (858, 33, 359, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '14:52:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (852, 33, 359, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '2:29:06', 2, 1, 0),
        (851, 33, 359, '2018-03-06 00:00:00', '14:09:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (896, 33, 260, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '6:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (897, 33, 260, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (907, 33, 348, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (908, 33, 348, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (893, 33, 350, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '14:36:40', 1, 1, 0),
        (915, 33, 350, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '17:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (913, 33, 359, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (914, 33, 359, '2018-03-07 00:00:00', '17:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (923, 33, 348, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (925, 33, 348, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '11:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (928, 33, 348, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '11:45:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (927, 33, 348, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '11:35:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (924, 33, 348, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '12:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (926, 33, 348, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '13:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (898, 33, 350, '2018-03-08 00:00:00', '11:42:57', 1, 1, 0),
        (906, 33, 206, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '8:14:43', 1, 1, 0),
        (905, 33, 260, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '8:12:53', 1, 1, 0),
        (972, 33, 348, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (911, 33, 350, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '10:43:59', 1, 1, 0),
        (912, 33, 350, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '10:44:22', 1, 1, 0),
        (917, 33, 350, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '12:44:48', 1, 1, 0),
        (929, 33, 350, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '15:18:17', 1, 1, 0),
        (921, 33, 350, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '12:50:14', 2, 1, 0),
        (918, 33, 359, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '12:44:48', 1, 1, 0),
        (922, 33, 359, '2018-03-09 00:00:00', '12:50:14', 2, 1, 0),
        (970, 33, 350, '2018-03-11 00:00:00', '11:25:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (968, 33, 260, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (962, 33, 348, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (969, 33, 348, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '9:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (951, 33, 350, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '8:54:07', 1, 1, 0),
        (953, 33, 350, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '10:31:29', 1, 1, 0),
        (954, 33, 350, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '10:34:18', 1, 1, 0),
        (950, 33, 350, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '8:21:11', 2, 1, 0),
        (952, 33, 350, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '9:02:26', 2, 1, 0),
        (955, 33, 359, '2018-03-12 00:00:00', '10:37:26', 1, 1, 0),
        (959, 33, 206, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '1:01:38', 1, 1, 0),
        (961, 33, 206, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '14:00:51', 1, 1, 0),
        (975, 33, 295, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '7:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (976, 33, 295, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '8:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (957, 33, 350, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '11:26:52', 1, 1, 0),
        (958, 33, 359, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '1:00:12', 1, 1, 0),
        (965, 33, 359, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '21:00:00', 1, 1, 0),
        (960, 33, 359, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '13:14:14', 2, 1, 0),
        (967, 33, 359, '2018-03-13 00:00:00', '22:00:00', 2, 1, 0),
        (964, 33, 350, '2018-03-14 00:00:00', '14:34:36', 2, 1, 0),
        (963, 33, 359, '2018-03-14 00:00:00', '13:45:25', 1, 1, 0)
    ;
```

Here is the query I used to return the data above:

```
SELECT  AttendanceID   , DepartmentID   , EmployeeID   , AttendanceDate   , AttendanceTime   , AttendanceTypeID   , AttendanceCodeID   , Submitted
FROM tblAttendance
WHERE AttendanceDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND AttendanceTypeID IN (1,2)  -- 1 = in, and 2 = out
AND AttendanceCodeID = 1
ORDER BY
AttendanceDate
,AttendanceTime
```

The tables added below show the steps that are needed to get the end results.
First a data example:

```
+------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
| EmployeeID | AttendanceDate | AttendanceTime | AttendanceTypeID |
+------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 2:32:36        |        1         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 2:48:54        |        1         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 2:49:11        |        1         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 2:52:19        |        1         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 13:32:00       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 13:53:00       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 13:35:00       |        2         |
| 350        | 3/6/18         | 14:06:00       |        2         |
| 350        | 3/7/18         | 14:36:40       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/7/18         | 17:00:00       |        2         |
| 350        | 3/8/18         | 11:42:57       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 10:43:59       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 10:44:22       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 12:44:48       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 15:18:17       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 12:50:14       |        2         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 10:43:59       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 10:44:22       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 12:44:48       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 15:18:17       |        1         |
| 350        | 3/9/18         | 12:50:14       |        2         |
+------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Second Pair up the matching data in out pairs, and get there time difference.

```
+------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| EmployeeID | AttendanceDate | AttendanceTime   | Pair Total       |
+------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| 350        | 3/6/18         |13:35:00 -13:32:00|     0:03:00      |
| 350        | 3/6/18         |14:06:00 -13:53:00|     0:13:00      |
| 350        | 3/7/18         |17:00:00 -14:36:40|     2:23:20      |
| 350        | 3/9/18         |12:44:48 -12:44:48|     0:05:26      |
+------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Third the compiled data for the employee during that week.

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+
| EmployeeID | AttendanceWeek    | AttendanceTime Total | 
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+
| 350        | 3/4/18 to 3/10/18 |     2:44:46          |
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Hope that this helps narrow the focus.

Thank you.

Comment: MJH, thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that Sunday is the default value for the start week.

```
--see what day is the default start day of the week
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
--set it to Sunday if value isn't 7
SET DATEFIRST 7;
```

I think I figured out what you were asking by using a `CTE`, a couple `SUM CASE` statements, and the [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2/25/2018 12:00AM';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '3/17/2018 11:59PM';

--Count number of 1's and 2's in a day
--Group by EmployeeId and AttendanceDate
WITH daily1And2 AS(
    SELECT EmployeeID,
       AttendanceDate,
           SUM(CASE WHEN AttendanceTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Num1',
           SUM(CASE WHEN AttendanceTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Num2'
    FROM tblAttendance
    WHERE AttendanceDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
          AND AttendanceTypeID IN (1,2)
          AND AttendanceCodeID = 1
    GROUP BY EmployeeID,AttendanceDate)

--Find the number of pairs and group by week
SELECT EmployeeID,
       DATEPART(wk,AttendanceDate)'Week', --Get Week
       --Getting the lowest of the 2 numbers, because that will
       --be the number of pairs, then summing for the week
       SUM(CASE WHEN Num1 > Num2 THEN Num2 ELSE Num1 END) 'Num1and2Pairs'
FROM daily1And2
GROUP BY EmployeeID,DATEPART(wk,AttendanceDate)
ORDER BY EmployeeID,DATEPART(wk,AttendanceDate)
```

Output:

```
+------------+------+---------------+
| EmployeeID | Week | Num1and2Pairs |
+------------+------+---------------+
|     114    |   9  |       0       |
|     206    |   9  |       1       |
|     206    |  10  |       1       |
|     206    |  11  |       0       |
|     260    |   9  |       1       |
|     260    |  10  |       2       |
|     260    |  11  |       0       |
|     295    |  11  |       1       |
|     344    |   9  |       1       |
|     348    |   9  |       1       |
|     348    |  10  |       4       |
|     348    |  11  |       1       |
|     350    |   9  |       2       |
|     350    |  10  |       4       |
|     350    |  11  |       2       |
|     359    |   9  |       0       |
|     359    |  10  |       4       |
|     359    |  11  |       2       |
|     361    |   9  |      10       |
+------------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: This a bit closer to what I'm thinking. Sometimes graphics are a better way to show what is needed, which I added above.  Thank you very much for your time.